# Stop the test Ad of mopub while getting live Ad's

Tags: ios, iphone, mopub

I am getting the live Mopub Live Ad's but has been getting the test Ad of Mopub while not loading the live Ad's.

how can stop the test Ad's of mopub?

[image: test Ad of mopub]

Comment: You should show us some code so we know how you're getting ads. Thanks.

Comment: can u please share me how can live add render in my app as i am getting only demo adds in my app while testing

Answer (score 2):

The demo ad can be disabled in the moPub dashboard under Order. You can either turn the line item off or delete the demo. I recommend just turning it off.

Comment: is it necessary to add third party ad network to fetch live ad? @Jerry Phillips

Comment: MoPub can supply ad content to you as well. If you are not getting ads send them a quick email to enable it. If something is different or has changed please comment to let me know.

Comment: I have face mopub account approval issue so i ask above question.
I have already send email to policy@mopub.com with up to date require information like payment information and iTunes app store url and Android package name.Currently my application already live in iTunes app store and Google play store.